# Integrity constraint violation on import

Tags: magento-1.9, import, magmi

I used the following code to clear all my products and unused attribute values in order to make a fresh re-import with the final CSVs:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_selection`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_type`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute_label`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_enabled_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_website`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock`;
INSERT  INTO `catalog_product_link_type`(`link_type_id`,`code`) VALUES (1,'relation'),(2,'bundle'),(3,'super'),(4,'up_sell'),(5,'cross_sell');
INSERT  INTO `catalog_product_link_attribute`(`product_link_attribute_id`,`link_type_id`,`product_link_attribute_code`,`data_type`) VALUES (1,2,'qty','decimal'),(2,1,'position','int'),(3,4,'position','int'),(4,5,'position','int'),(6,1,'qty','decimal'),(7,3,'position','int'),(8,3,'qty','decimal');
INSERT  INTO `cataloginventory_stock`(`stock_id`,`stock_name`) VALUES (1,'Default');
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity`;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;


    DELETE o, v
      FROM `eav_attribute` a
INNER JOIN `eav_attribute_option` o ON a.`attribute_id` = o.`attribute_id`
INNER JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` v ON v.`option_id` = o.`option_id`
INNER JOIN `eav_entity_type` t ON t.`entity_type_id` = a.`entity_type_id`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` pi ON o.`option_id` = pi.`value` AND o.`attribute_id` = pi.`attribute_id`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` pv ON o.`option_id` = pv.`value` AND o.`attribute_id` = pv.`attribute_id`
     WHERE pi.`entity_id` IS NULL
       AND pv.`entity_id` IS NULL
       AND t.`entity_type_code` = "catalog_product"
       AND a.is_user_defined = 1

SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_export ; 
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_import ; 
TRUNCATE log_customer ; 
TRUNCATE log_quote ; 
TRUNCATE log_summary ; 
TRUNCATE log_summary_type ; 
TRUNCATE log_url ; 
TRUNCATE log_url_info ; 
TRUNCATE log_visitor ; 
TRUNCATE log_visitor_info ; 
TRUNCATE log_visitor_online ; 
TRUNCATE report_event ;
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

But now when I try to make a fresh import I get the following errors:

```
 SKU CLSAN - 1 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4-1' for key 'PRIMARY' -
SKU CLSAN - 2 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4-1' for key 'PRIMARY' - ERROR ON RECORD #4
SKU KPBWFS - 3 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '7-5' for key 'PRIMARY' -
SKU KPBWFS - 4 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '7-5' for key 'PRIMARY' - ERROR ON RECORD #7
SKU KPBWNP - 5 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '10-8' for key 'PRIMARY' -
SKU KPBWNP - 6 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '10-8' for key 'PRIMARY' - ERROR ON RECORD #10
SKU KPBWSP - 7 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '13-11' for key 'PRIMARY' -
SKU KPBWSP - 8 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '13-11' for key 'PRIMARY' - ERROR ON RECORD #13
SKU CLBSD - 9 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '21-14' for key 'PRIMARY' -
SKU CLBSD - 10 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '21-14' for key 'PRIMARY' - ERROR ON RECORD #21
SKU CLBSK - 11 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '34-22' for key 'PRIMARY' -
SKU CLBSK - 12 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '34-22' for key 'PRIMARY' - ERROR ON RECORD #34
SKU LURS10W - 13 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '38-35' for key 'PRIMARY' -
SKU LURS10W - 14 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '38-35' for key 'PRIMARY' - ERROR ON RECORD #38
```

I have tried clearing cache and re-indexing before import but didn't seem to work, any suggestions on how to resolve this problem is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Already table data exists in '4-1' thats why its throws that error. Could you please take backup of database and truncate that data.

Comment: @Venkat could you please narrow me down on which table I should look for this values?

Comment: From the above csv you have inserting record to this table `catalog_product_link_type`,  `catalog_product_link_attribute`, `cataloginventory_stock`. Please check data of this tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem and though that someone might find it handy in the future, so my database product cleaning query was missing 1 truncate of the table catalog_product_relations which left behind data, thus generating the data integrity constrains.